# Adding inline style attributes to Wordpress Menu Items

Tags: wordpress, menu, styles, inline

Using the latest version of WP, is it possible to add inline style attributes to a wordpress menu item from within the wordpress menu panel?

So for example, I have a menu where for whatever reason, I need to position the menu items absolutely. I want my client to be able to go into the WP menu panel and simply add a style of "left: xx%" to any item.

I know this can be done via the stylesheet - but was hoping there was also a way to do this as described above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[**Shortcodes Pro**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shortcodes-pro/) is a great plugin for this.